# How do I get a field in bash's job list using awk?

Tags: bash, awk, jobs

I wanted to write a function to retrieve a field from the list of background jobs in bash. For example to get a specific argument.

Let's say I send vim to the background, so "jobs" displays this list:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 vim ~/.bashrc
```

My function looks like this:

```
function jf {
    echo `jobs | awk 'NR==$1{print $$2}'`;
}
```

I then call it like this:

```
jf 1 4
```

I would want it to return the 4th column of the 1st line, which would be "~/.bashrc", but it doesn't. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Too many `$`s: `awk 'NR==1{print $4}'`.

Comment: I need the $ to refer to the respective arguments. The function is supposed to receive the line number as first, and the column number as the second argument.

Comment: `$1`, `$2` and alike are not command line arguments in `awk`, but fields of the current record.

Comment: I know, but shouldn't bash substitute the arguments with their values before it executes awk? So that $1 becomes 1 and $2 becomes 4 in my example. I mean, that's the point of using the dollar sign in a bash function, isn't it?

Comment: Not inside single quoted strings. `awk "NR==$1{print \$$2}"`

Comment: Unfortunately, when I substitute the single quotes with double quotes in my example, it returns some integer value. I assume the back ticks are to blame for this. However, if I don't use echo and drop the back ticks, it seems to work fine. Looks like I overcomplicated things. Thanks a lot for this hint, this is a more general and therefore better solution than using functionality specific to awk to pass shell variables.

Comment: The integer value is probably the current PID followed by `2` - `$$` is a shell variable that holds the current process's ID.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell `awk` that you want to pass in values from shell variables. Something like this in your function definition should do the trick:

```
function jf {
    echo `jobs | awk -v LINENO=$1 -v COLUMNNO=$2 'NR==LINENO {print $COLUMNNO}'`
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work great! The solution hinted at by manatwork is more general though.

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes made bash not substitute arguments. As manatwork mentioned, double quotes are interpreted less strictly.

manatwork wrote:

```
awk "NR==$1{print \$$2}"
```

Still, the "echo `...`" part in my function posed a problem, but it seems I overcomplicated things and it isn't needed at all. This new function works for me:

```
function jf {
    jobs | awk "NR==$1{print \$$2}";
}
```